# if i know that every Cauchy sequence converge then exists an unique $x\in \mathop{\cap}_{n=1}^\infty I_n $?

Tags: real-analysis, cauchy-sequences

I have to prove this: if every Cauchy sequence is convergent then if ${(I_n)}_{n\ge 1}$ is a sequence of closed intervals whose lengths tend to zero, so exists an unique $x\in \mathop{\cap}_{n=1}^\infty I_n $. Should i prove that ${(I_n)}_n$ is Cauchy and converge to $x$? Thanks in advance.

PD:the intervals are nested $I_1\supseteq I_2\supseteq I_3\supseteq\ldots$

Comment: No. And the intervals have to be nested: $I_1\supseteq I_2\supseteq I_3\supseteq\ldots$

Comment: It does not make sense to say a sequence of intervals is Cauchy.  A sequence of points can be Cauchy.

Comment: @Gedgar: It is a Cauchy filter. But I suppose if the O.P. knew that, he wouldn't have to ask this question…

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

If $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$, consider the sequences $(a_n)_{n\ge 0}$ and $(b_n)_{n\ge 0}$.